# Add a label to an image SWT Java

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to add a label under the image. But doing it in the following way doesn't dispay any label. Only the image is displayed.

```
    public void open() {
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    createContents();
    Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(40, 21, 217, 178);
    lblNewLabel.setText("New Label");


    Image i = new Image(display, "where the image is");
    lblNewLabel.setImage(i);


    CLabel cLabel = new CLabel(shell, SWT.ARROW_RIGHT);

    cLabel.setImage(i);
    cLabel.setText("SWT CLabel");
    shell.open();
    shell.layout();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
}


protected void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell();
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText("SWT Application");


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in this way :

```
        Label lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData gd_lblNewLabel_1 = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_lblNewLabel_1.widthHint = 193;
        gd_lblNewLabel_1.heightHint = 193;
        lblNewLabel_1.setLayoutData(gd_lblNewLabel_1);
        Image image = new Image(display, "where the image is");
        lblNewLabel_1.setImage(image);
        lblNewLabel_1 = new Label(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("image label");
```

Comment: The Javadoc for `Label` starts with, "Instances of this class represent a non-selectable user interface object that displays a string **or** image." (emphasis mine)